# Data Concurrency and Consistency on a Oracle Database Server with multiple instance

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can anyone please explain how data consistency is handled in a multi-instanced Oracle Database when multiple users across the instances are trying to access the same data ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Oracle uses a technique called *Cache Fusion* (see for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPRC/intro_tdprc.htm#TDPRC117)) to exchange “dirty” cached blocks between the instances when they are needed elsewhere.

This is relevant only when data are written — as long as everybody reads, there is no problem.

Comment: Really? I believe you, but it sounds surprisingly stupid to introduce an unnecessary concurrency handicap where it is not necessary...

Comment: Why ship clean blocks over the interconnect rather than keeping a copy in the SGA of every instance?

Comment: How do you think a copy gets into the SGA?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the concepts well enough, but I thought that "cache" refers to the SGA and "fusion" to the shipping of cached blocks via the interconnect, no?

Comment: Correct. So if I am on instance 1 and the data blocks I need are on instance 2, then I can ship them to my instance via cache fusion.

Comment: I see - that may be cheaper than reading from storage... maybe. Thanks for the explanation.